# Python - merging of csv files with one axis in common

Tags: python, csv

I need to merge two csv files, `A.csv` and `B.csv`, with one axis in common, extract:

```
9.358,3.0
9.388,2.0
```

and

```
8.551,2.0
8.638,2.0
```

I want the final file C.csv to have the following pattern:

```
8.551,0.0,2.0
8.638,0.0,2.0
9.358,3.0,0.0
9.388,2.0,0.0
```

How to you suggest to do it? Should I go for a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read from each file, writing out to the output file and adding in the 'missing' column:

```
import csv

with open('c.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
    # Python 3: use open('c.csv', 'w', newline='') instead
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)

    # copy a.csv across, adding a 3rd column
    with open('a.csv', 'rb') as incsv:
        # Python 3: use open('a.csv', newline='') instead
        reader = csv.reader(incsv)
        writer.writerows(row + [0.0] for row in reader)

    # copy b.csv across, inserting a 2nd column
    with open('b.csv', 'rb') as incsv:
        # Python 3: use open('b.csv', newline='') instead
        reader = csv.reader(incsv)
        writer.writerows(row[:1] + [0.0] + row[1:] for row in reader)
```

The `writer.writerows()` lines do all the work; a generator expression loops over the rows in each `reader`, either appending a column or inserting a column in the middle.

This works with whatever size of input CSVs you have, as only some read and write buffers are held in memory. Rows are processed in iterative fashion without ever needing to hold all of the input or output files in memory.

Comment: Thanks for that! Everything goes fine with `a.csv`, but not with `b.csv`: I only got the first row and the zeros, but not the second row...

Comment: @albus_c: My initial version didn't use slicing; are you using my most recent edit?

Comment: Yes I still miss one column of data when dealing with `b.csv`

Comment: @albus_c: Can you create a pastie or gist with a samples of `a.csv` and `b.csv` and the produced output? I suspect something is up with your `b.csv` file in that it is not read properly. You could also try opening **just** `b.csv` and printing each row (`for row in reader: print row`) and seeing if that works correctly.

Comment: I recompiled a few times, and everything runs fine now ;) Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

dat1 = np.genfromtxt('dat1.txt', delimiter=',')
dat2 = np.genfromtxt('dat2.txt', delimiter=',')

dat1 = np.insert(dat1, 2, 0, axis=1)
dat2 = np.insert(dat2, 1, 0, axis=1)

dat = np.vstack((dat1, dat2))

np.savetxt('dat.txt', dat, delimiter=',', fmt='%.3f')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution using a dictionary, which will work for *any* number of files:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def process(*filenames):
    lines = {}
    index = 0
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename,'rU') as f:
            for line in f:
                v1, v2 = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
                lines.setdefault(v1,{})[index] = v2
        index += 1
    for line in sorted(lines):
        print(line, end=',')
        for i in range(index):
            print(lines[line].get(i,0.0), end=',' if i < index-1 else '\n')

process('A.csv','B.csv')
```

prints

```
8.551,0.0,2.0
8.638,0.0,2.0
9.358,3.0,0.0
9.388,2.0,0.0
```

Comment: I got the error `print(line, end=',')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Works fine for me... are you using Python 2 or 3?